# Items with border in ListView freeze app when scrolling

Tags: flutter

This is code of `ListView` item

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey,width:0.3))),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm","ru_Ru").format(DateTime.now())),SizedBox(width: 5.0,height: 45.0,)],
  ),
);
```

When I scroll down and up, app freeze completely, so I have to kill it.

If I comment `decoration` it works without any problems

**This code works**

```
return Container(
  //decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey,width:0.3))),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm","ru_Ru").format(DateTime.now())),SizedBox(width: 5.0,height: 45.0,)],
  ),
);
```

Comment: make an issue, this is likely to be a bug

Comment: Actually, works totally fine

Comment: I think, problem in the mechanism that destroys and restores items gone beyond the visible area. I test it on real device (android 4.4), may be on newer devices this problem doesn't happens